# How to use Reduced Dataset (a subset of a larger table) to improve query performance times?

Tags: sql

If I dump SPECIFIC data into a new table for performance reasons (reduce overall query times) and SELECT from just the reduced dataset, isn't that performance bottleneck still there because then THAT table needs to be updated?

Comment: This really doesn't make a lot of sense.  Step one is to determine what your bottleneck actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have so much more to worry about.

1. **Where is the bottleneck?** When querying a subset using a direct query will bring the same actual data as when querying a derived table. When you have a lot to put over the line, performance gain may be less big due to this. You have to know the actual cause to know whether this will have the effect you want;
2. **Actual gain.** How much does the table get queried? How often does it get updated? Those are major elements on the decision if this will bring you something;
3. **Indexes.** When indices on the main table are well maintained, the performance of a derived table without will be probably less.